# toExponential() for large numbers with significant fractionDigits only

Tags: javascript, jasmine-jquery

I want to format large numbers (>1e5) in exponential notation with limited number of fraction digits but skip unnecessary zero digits.

```
expect(print(100000)).toBe('1e5');
expect(print(123456)).toBe('1,234e5');
expect(print(101000)).toBe('1,01e5');
```

`value.toExponential(3)` gives me `1.000e+5`, `1,234e+5`, `1,010+5`

`value.toExponential()` gives me `1e+5`, `1,23456e+5`, `1,01+5`

I could imagine something like `123456 -> 1.23456 -> "1.234" -> 1.234 -> 123400 -> "1.234e+5"`, but I hope there is a better way of doing this. If not, what is a good implementation of such a conversion.

Comment: I would think  `123456 -> 1234.56 -> 1235 -> "1235" -> "1.235e5"` is the easiest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need any extra `0` before the `e`, one could do like this:

```js
value.toExponential(3).replace(/0+e/,'e').replace('.e','e')
```

Or you could just do this:

```js
value.toExponential().replace(/[,.](\d{3})\d*e/,'.$1e')
```

Replace `3` with the required number of decimals.